# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Installer error

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-express

I installed Microsoft SQL Server Express with Tools. Then I just wanted to install Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, but I can't continue due to  this error:

[image: Error, cant select anything to continue]

It doesn't allow me to continue and I cant select anything. I would help any given help, thanks!

Comment: The error message tells you **exactly** what to do. *Click OK to close this dialog box. Review the errors at the bottom of the setup page, then provide valid parameters or click Help for more information.* Have you tried doing that?

Comment: I cannot do anything! Everything is unselected! I cannot click on anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Installed SQL express server, so SQL Server Management Studio is considered as a shared component and it is installed as a feature of SQL Server.

The error asks for the SQL server setup (not the instance of sql express you installed).

To install SSMS, select "Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server 2014" and you must define the instance to which you’re adding feature in the drop-down list below the second radio-button.

For step by step installation read: [How to install SQL Server 2014 Management Studio](http://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-install-sql-server-2014-management-studio/)

N.B.: I advice to install the last SP2